# Laravel changed configured database name

Tags: laravel-5

I have two laravel api projects,

1-used for mysql database and another used for mssql database

I called mysql project api service to get orders and some data related with order are exists in mssql and I have written a call of curl in 1st project to get from another information related with order from mssql project api (mssql service api url = localhost/laravelmssql/api/getorderInfo/OrderID)

mssql service call working fine from browser

but when I call it from 1st project with curl its getting wrong database which is configured in 1st project

**Note:**
This is adding correct database connection info in $_SERVER when I call it from browser

```
[DB_PORT] => 1433
[DB_DATABASE] => MSSQL DATABASE
[DB_USERNAME] => MSSQL_USERNAME
[DB_PASSWORD] => MSSQL_PASSWORD
```

but when I call it from curl the $_SERVER don't have these above variables

I have updated code

2nd-project controller for 
    class OrderController extends BaseController{

```
    public function getOrderDetail(){
//  echo env('DB_DATABASE').'-'.str_random(10); // ITS GETTING 1ST CONFIGURE DATABASE NAME

//      echo '<pre>';print_r($_SERVER);echo '</pre>'; die;
//
//      echo '<pre>';print_r($_SERVER);echo '</pre>';
        return OrderDetailsModel::getOrderDetail(1);
    }
}
```

1st-Project Call

//NOT WORKING

```
$curl_handle=curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL,'http://apiproject/api/getOrderDetail/1');
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 2);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$query = curl_exec($curl_handle);
curl_close($curl_handle);
echo $query;
```

//NOT WORKING

```
dd(file_get_contents('http://apiproject/api/getOrderDetail/1'));
```

//NOT WORKING

```
$response = Curl::to(env('MSSQLAPILINK').'get/getOrderDetail/'.$orderID)->withHeaders([
    'DB_DATABASE:0000',
    'DB_USERNAME:0000',
    'DB_PASSWORD:0000',
    'DB_PREFIX:000',
])->get();
dd($response);
```

Comment: Please share some code

Comment: @NirajShah I've added code

Comment: Why are you passing DB details in headers? Why not just configure each project with DB details. This is very insecure.

Comment: both projects are configured in .env but this is just a try.

Comment: Would highly recommend you don't send DB credentials in headers. Rely on the `.env` files or find a secure of way of sending credentials across if it's required.

Comment: @NirajShah dear said that its just a try.